# Is $\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbf{X}_i \mathbf{X}_i^T$ a biased estimator of $E[\mathbf{X}_i\mathbf{X}_i^T]$ in multiple regression?

Tags: probability, statistics, convergence-divergence, regression, covariance

The classical multiple regression model for $n$ iid observations is
$$
\mathbf{Y} = \mathbf{X}\beta + \epsilon,
$$
where
$$
\mathbf{X}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf{X}_{1}^T \\
\mathbf{X}_{2}^T \\
\vdots \\
\mathbf{X}_{n}^T \\
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & X_{11} & X_{12} & \dots & X_{1p}   \\
1 & X_{21} & X_{22} & \dots & X_{2p}   \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots \vdots \\
1 & X_{n1} & X_{n2} & \dots & X_{np}
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

Assuming that the matrix $E[\mathbf{X}_i\mathbf{X}_i^T]$ exists, the weak law of large numbers gives that
$$
\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbf{X}_i \mathbf{X}_i^T \stackrel{p}{\to} E[\mathbf{X}_i\mathbf{X}_i^T].
$$

So we have convergence in probability, but I am more interested in convergence in expectation (and also the expectation on finite samples).

Is $\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbf{X}_i \mathbf{X}_i^T$ a biased estimator of $E[\mathbf{X}_i\mathbf{X}_i^T]$?

If it is biased for finite $n$, what about the case when $n \to \infty$, i.e., is $\lim_{n \to \infty} E[\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbf{X}_i \mathbf{X}_i^T] \to E[\mathbf{X}_i\mathbf{X}_i^T]$? If we assume uniform integrability (UI) of the elements of the matrix $\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbf{X}_i \mathbf{X}_i^T$ then we get convergence in expectation. But do we need to assume $\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbf{X}_i \mathbf{X}_i^T$ is UI or is it actually already UI without any assumptions?

Comment: notation needs some adjustment -- the symbol X_n is overloaded, right?

Comment: Ok, I removed the $n$ subscript from the matrix $\mathbf{X}$.

Comment: if the elements of $X$ are all gaussian, I believe that the estimator is unbiased for any sample size, and I think it follows from Bishwal, J., & Peña, E. A. (2008). A note on inference in a bivariate normal distribution model. PO Box, 14006, 27709-4006.  If the elements of $X$ are general, I'm not sure

Comment: Yes it is the general case I am interested in. Or at least the general case with minimal assumptions as assuming all the elements of $X$ are Gaussian is too restrictive.